# lein run exits without running all of my -main function

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Here's my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject fixurls "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    :description "Fixurls"
    :url "https://github.com/swizzard/fixurls"
    :license {:name "WTFPL"
                :url "http://www.wtfpl.net/"}
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
              [clj-http "0.9.2"]
              [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.4"]
              [me.raynes/fs "1.4.4"]
              ]
    :plugins [[lein-gorilla "0.2.0"]]
    :jvm-opts ["-Xmx4g" "-Xms2g" "-Xss1g" "-server"]
    :main ^:skip-aot fixurls.core
)
```

Here's `~/clojure-stuff/fixurls/src/core.clj`:

```
(ns fixurls.core
    (:require
    [clj-http.client :as client]
    [clojure.string :as string]
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [me.raynes.fs :as fs]
    [clojure.data.json :as json]
    )
    (:import [java.net URL])
    (:gen-class)
)
...
(defn process-file [in-file] (spit (get-fixed-name in-file)
                          (update-file in-file)))

(defn process-files [] (map process-file valid-files))

(defn -main [] (do (println "Hello, world!") (process-files)))
```

When I run `lein run`, all that happens, after a pause, is the printing of `Hello, world!` to `stdout`, and then lein exits. I've independently verified that the `(process-files)` part of `-main` isn't getting called. I can run `(-main)` from the repl and it works properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` function is lazy, and is not guaranteed process any input unless the corresponding output is accessed. If you are using `map` for side effects alone, wrap it in `dorun`. If you also need the result, use `doall` to force processing of the entire input.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Guess I still have to wrap my head around the laziness stuff...