# Clojure and Leiningen: Why is `doall` needed in this example?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

I'm currently using Leiningen to learn Clojure and I'm confused about the requirement of `doall` for running this function:

```
;; take a function (for my purposes, println for output formatting) and repeat it n times
(defn repeat [f n] (for [i (range n)] (f)))
```

`(repeat println 2)` works just fine in an REPL session, but not when running with `lein run` unless I include the `doall` wrapper. `(doall (repeat println 2))` works and I'm curious why. Without it, `lein run` doesn't show the two blank lines in the output.

I also have:

```
(defmacro newPrint1 [& args] `'(println ~args))
(defmacro newPrint2 [& args] `'(println ~@args))
```

The first function I thought of myself. The next two macros are examples from a tutorial video I'm following on Udemy. Even if I wrap the macro calls with doall, such as `(doall (newPrint1 1 2 3))`, `lein run` produces no output, but `(newPrint1 1 2 3)` in a terminal REPL session produces the desired output of `(clojure.core/println (1 2 3))` as it does in the video tutorial. Why doesn't `doall` work here?

Comment: Please provide **exact** steps to reproduce. A (shortest possible, per [mcve] guidelines) `project.clj`, the complete namespace it invokes (with everything unrelated to the behavior at hand removed), etc.

Comment: ...here's the thing -- the general question requires going into details about AOT compilation, and isn't really scoped narrowly enough to be answerable (moreover, the issue could be caused by something completely unrelated, like an error in the `project.clj` causing a different namespace to be executed, or confusion between return value and side effects). We can't tell you *all* the ways AOT compilations to REPL-style inline evaluation, but if you show us the reproducer, we can describe whatever *one* difference is causing your problem.

Comment: Does `(doall (repeat println 2))` work properly? If so, you might think about editing your question to (narrowly!) ask why that specific `doall` is necessary, rather than asking something much, much broader. (Basically, because the REPL prints results of evaluating commands, it forces lazy sequences -- such as those generated by `map` and `for` -- to be realized).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy wrapping it in `doall` worked for the repeat statement, but not for the macros. I'll edit the question to reflect this. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24375701

Comment: BTW - [`repeat` is a standard Clojure function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeat)

Comment: Your `repeat` is the standard [`repeatedly`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeatedly) with the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` creates a lazy sequence.  This lazy sequence is returned.  The P in REPL (read eval Print loop) prints the sequence, thus realizing it.  For realizing, the code to produce each element is run.

If you do not use the sequence, it is not realized, so the code is never run.  In non-interactive use, this is likely the case.  As noted, `doall` forces realization.

If you want to do side-effects, `doseq` is often better suited than `for`.